# Alt+Tab switching does work BUT closes the applications afterwards

Tags: unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys, application-switcher, ccsm

Since today morning my 16.04 ubuntu systems behaves strange. When switching through the open tabs with **Alt+Tab the switching works, but the tabs are immediately closed after switching.**

In my Window-Management of the ccsm I did not change anything and I cannot find the reason.

The other thing is that I have now an English keyboard layout although it was always German. With sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration I can fix it temporarily, but after a restart it is again English. Cannot imagine that both problems are related, but this are somehow the new functions or nonfunctions of my system...

`lsb_release -a` gives this output:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Comment: Have you rebooted the system to see if your alt+tab problem goes away? Are you talking about in a web browser, or nautilus? And your keyboard defaulting to English, isn't that what you want, or is that a typo? Cheers, Al

Answer (score 1):

I'm experiencing the same problem, with a slight difference that I have allocated Super + Tab to switching applications.

**Here's one remedy** : use another window switcher.

> So anyhow on to how to change the alt-tab application switcher in ubuntu unity.
>
> sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
> sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins
>
> Open compizconfig-settings-manager with alt-F2, type ccsm.
>
> Scroll down to "Ubuntu Unity Plugin". Choose the tab "Switcher". Disable the alt-tab and shift-alt-tab key bindings. ("Key to start the switcher" and "Key to switch to the previous window in the Switcher".
> Click the "Back" button.
>
> Scroll down to the "Window management" section. Here you can select another switcher.
> I enable the "Static Application Switcher", resolve any potential conflicts by setting the setting for "Static Application Switcher".
> Now you can tweak the switcher by clicking on it. I have changed alt-tab and shift-alt-tab to "Next window (All windows)" and "Prev window (All windows)".

(Quoted from https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2211863 ).

**So far this is working for me.**
I haven't experienced the problem since I switched to the other window switcher (that actually implies that the original Unity window manager is causing the problem, and not conflicting keybindings).